# Debian packaging a GPL software with CC0 and public domain sounds

Tags: license-compatibility, debian

I want to submit to Debian a software licensed under GPL3. However, the software bundles [various sound tracks](https://github.com/rafaelmardojai/blanket/blob/master/SOUNDS_LICENSING.md#sounds-licensing) released under different licenses (mostly CC0, CC BY, Public Domain).

1. Does Debian policy allow submitting such a software?
2. How to write the Debian copyright file in this case, when the real name and the email addresses of the authors of the sound track are not available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Debian policy allows submitting such a software. It is common practice to publish multimedia assets for open source software as CC. CC0 is just fine ([see here](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#CC0)), even more restrictive licenses are okay.

This is often done in games. For example, Debian includes "Supertuxcart", which uses lots of assets published as CC0 and CC-BY-SA. [See this example](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/supertuxkart/code/stk-assets/textures/License.txt).

The second source also answers your second question. There are some copyright holders mentioned without e-mail addresses.